# Dump packets collected with mitmproxy

Tags: mitmproxy

I was using `mitmproxy` to see the traffic. Now I want to store all of those packets into a file. Is that possible or should I use `mitmdump` next time?

Comment: Ooh, my bad for not noticing that, thanks!

Comment: @Robert can you turn this into an answer so I can mark it as such?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not matter if you use `mitmproxy` or `mitmdump`.

Both programs support nearly the same functionality, except that mitmdump is a command-line tool that does not shows a GUI.

For saving the captured web traffic you can start mitmproxy or mirmdump using the `-w` command-line option:

```
mitmproxy -w outfile
mitmdump -w outfile
```

https://docs.mitmproxy.org/stable/tools-mitmdump/