# mitmproxy to export web traffic as JSON

Tags: json, dump, mitmproxy

Trying to save the captured web traffic of the raw HTTP request/response while using `mitmproxy`:

- Followed https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy/blob/main/examples/contrib/jsondump.py with
  `mitmproxy -s /pkg/mitmproxy/jsondump.py`, and with

  ```
    $ cat ~/.mitmproxy/config.yaml
    dump_destination: "/tmp/mitmproxy.log.json"
  ```

  But my "`/tmp/mitmproxy.log.json`" was never written to.
- Then tried `mitmproxy -w outfile` as per [Dump packets collected with mitmproxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62483878/dump-packets-collected-with-mitmproxy), but the output is not in JSON format
- Then tried `mitmproxy -s /pkg/mitmproxy/jsondump.py -w outfile` and the output is still not in JSON format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mitmproxy currently has no JSON export. We're tentatively planning to support HAR export soon though. There's a community-contributed example for this here, which I think is in better shape than the jsondump one: https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy/blob/main/examples/contrib/har_dump.py